# Plot multiple embedded charts on separate sheets from shared data

Tags: vba, charts, plot, series

my semi-working code below plots data from my "sheet1" to a chart, then moves it to its own sheet and embeds it there. All data is on "sheet1". Each chart needs its own new page. Every iteration uses the same X-axis values, but separate Y-axis values (can be seen below)

My issue is in the second iteration (where I look to plot different columns from the same sheet). My code below doesn't differentiate that each chart is different, and plots the last iteration twice. I realize there is probably a cleaner way to code this overall, but I am very new to VBA and this way allows me to follow.

My gut told me to change Active.Chart to Graph1 and Graph2, respectively per iteration but when I tried this, nothing different happened. How do I change my syntax to tell VBA to start a new chart on a new page with new titles, etc. each iteration?

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction on this! I know it's simple but I am having a headache figuring it out.

```
'Plot Forces, Horizontal
Sub PlotResults()
On Error Resume Next
Range("A1").Select 'Prevent ghost plots
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = ("Graph1")

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Primary"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$A$10:$A$369"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Sheet1'!$B$20:$B$369"

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Secondary"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$A$10:$A$369"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='Sheet1'!$C$20:$C$369"

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Total"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$A$10:$A$369"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "='Sheet1'!$D$20:$D$369"
'Titles
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = ("Unbalance Forces, X" & vbCrLf & Model) 'NEED TO FIX THIS
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Crank Angle, Degrees"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Force (LBS)"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
'Formatting
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
ActiveChart.HasLegend = True
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .MaximumScale = 360
    .MinimumScale = 0
    .MajorUnit = 30
End With
With ActiveChart.Parent 'resize/reposition
    .Height = 525
    .Width = 900
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 100
End With
'Embed chart in own window
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph2").Activate
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Force, X"






'Plot Moments, Horizontal
Range("A1").Select 'Prevent ghost plots
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = ("Graph2")

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Primary"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$A$10:$A$369"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Sheet1'!$G$20:$G$369"

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Secondary"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$A$10:$A$369"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='Sheet1'!$H$20:$H$369"

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Total"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "='Sheet1'!$A$10:$A$369"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "='Sheet1'!$I$20:$I$369"
'Titles
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = ("Unbalance Moments, X" & vbCrLf & Model) 'NEED TO FIX THIS
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Crank Angle, Degrees"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Moment (FT-LBS)"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
'Formatting
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
ActiveChart.HasLegend = True
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .MaximumScale = 360
    .MinimumScale = 0
    .MajorUnit = 30
End With
With ActiveChart.Parent 'resize/reposition
    .Height = 525
    .Width = 900
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 100
End With
'Embed chart in own window
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph2").Activate
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Moment, X"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay everyone, I stumbled on the solution. It is very simple. Just add the following code at the end of each plotting iteration (after moving the chart to its own sheet and embedding it yet before calling the next sub routine or ending the current sub routine)

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'avoid multiple last plots issue
```

This ensures that after your chart is plotted, the sheet with data (in my case, sheet1) is selected again, therefore your ActiveSheet and ActiveChart command understands that a new chart is being created. That is all!